# Flutter Camera modify the Stream and then display

Tags: android, flutter, camera, mobile-application

I want to build a android App that can modify the Stream on Camera (like adding some icon on the camera preview) .

I got an sample code from official website of Flutter https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera#1-add-the-required-dependencies

How can I modify the sample code to achieve my goal?

Any idea?

Thanks.

The executable code to achieve my goal.